# how to calculate doping concentration in the base

Tags: semiconductors

how to calculate doping concentration in the base, and emitter, collector of SiC ?

In the neamen book dont teach that. just propose the constant number. so can you help me?
I hope to calculate NB, NC, NE. i know mobility and Nv, NC
cuz I am calculating about SiC parameters. not Si.

Comment: You'll have to use calibrated equipment in appropriate ways in order to elicit out the detailed model parameters for the device. From these, and some ideas about the 3D physical characteristics of the device, you can set up the various 3D integral equations to *back out* the dopant concentrations. I've done this in the isolated case of one Hamamatsu photodiode where I needed to know these things because I was using it for unusual pyrometry accuracy needs, using thin-film filters, and Hamamatsu wasn't very obliging. So it can be done. But it's a lot of work.

Comment: @jonk thank you to reply!! umm.. I tried that, but from intrinsic concentration ni was so weird. (at 300K) haha